# terminology needed regarding convex bodies

Tags: convex-analysis, terminology

Let $K$ be a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I'm looking for a term for a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$
that is zero on $\partial K$, negative on the interior of $K$,
and positive on the exterior of $K$.
Moreover, if the gradient of $f$ is defined at a point on $\partial K$,
then it must be non-zero.
Such a function always exists - e.g. the *signed distance* to $\partial K$,
but for some $K$ a *different* function is easier to compute,
or more convenient in some way.
Obviously there are infinitely many such functions for a given $K$.
Many convex bodies are canonically *defined* by a function like this (e.g. the unit ball),
but many are not.